# Не получается удалить 1-ый элемент с начала в очереди

Tags: c, структуры

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

struct list {
    int item;
    list *next;
public:
    list() {}
    list(int val, list *Next) : item(val), next(Next) {}        
}*head = NULL;

list *lastItem(list *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return 0;
    else {
        while (head->next != NULL)
            head = head->next;
    }

    return head;
}

void pushBeginning(list **head, int data)
{
    *head = new list(data, *head);    
}

void pushEnd(list **head, int number)
{
    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = new list(number, *head);
    }
    else {
        list *last = lastItem(*head);   
        last->next = new list(number, last->next);
    }
}

void delStart(list *head)
{
    list *tmp = head->next;
    list *current = head;
    delete current;
    head = tmp;
}

void delEnd(list *head)
{
    list *last = lastItem(head);
    list *tmp = head; 

    while (tmp->next != last)
        tmp = tmp->next;

    tmp->next = last->next;
    delete(last);
    head = tmp;

}

void show(list *head)
{
    if (head) {
        cout << head->item << ' ';
        show(head->next);
    }
    else cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    //head = new list();    
    //list *head = NULL;    
    pushBeginning(&head, 1);
    pushEnd(&head, 1000);
    pushEnd(&head, 1);
    pushEnd(&head, 15);
    pushEnd(&head, 150);
    show(head);
    delEnd(head);
    show(head);
    delStart(head);
    show(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а минимальный пример можно? На первый взгляд проблем нет. Не считая того, что присваивается в локальную переменную. Зачем в функциях перекрывать `head` локальной глобальную?

Comment: делаю всё по книге, в книге был приведён пример с добавлением в начало, я пытаюсь функционал сделать больше, но show(head) не выводит как надо

Comment: скажем так, в `delStart` или передавайте `list **head` или вообще ничего не передавайте.

Comment: я сделал функцию show() без параметров, почему она выводиться один раз на экран?

Comment: потому что вы её зачем-то сделали рекурсивной. В ней без параметра не обойтись (оставив рекурсию), но назовите его тогда не head а как-нибудь например current

Comment: Благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

потому что функция

```
void delStart(list *head)
{
    list *tmp = head->next;
    list *current = head;
    delete current;
    head = tmp;
}
```

принимает указатель который остаётся указывать туда же куда и указывал до вызова, так как адрес указателя копируется в функцию, оригинал не меняется. нужно передать указатель на указатель, тоесть так:

```
void delStart(list **head)
{
    list *tmp = *head->next;
    list *current = *head;
    delete current;
    *head = tmp;
}
```